# C:\xampp\htdocs\blueberry-test\wp-includes\script-loader.php on line 2407

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, xampp

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_current_screen() in C:\xampp\htdocs\blueberry-test\wp-includes\script-loader.php:2407 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\blueberry-test\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(307): wp_global_styles_render_svg_filters('') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\blueberry-test\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\blueberry-test\wp-includes\plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\blueberry-test\wp-includes\general-template.php(3074): do_action('wp_body_open') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\blueberry-test\wp-content\themes\blueberrys\header-home.php(35): wp_body_open() #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\blueberry-test\wp-includes\template.php(770): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\blueberry-test\wp-includes\template.php(716): load_template('C:\xampp\htdocs...', true, Array) #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\blueberry-test\wp-includes\general-template.php(48): locate_template(Array, true, true, Array) #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\blueberry-test\wp-content\themes\blueberrys\inc\woocommerce\storefront-woocommerce-template-functions.php(9): get_header('home') #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\blueberry-test\wp-content\themes\blueberrys\functions.php(47): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\blueberry-test\wp-settings.php(566): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\blueberry-test\wp-config.php(96): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\blueberry-test\wp-load.php(50): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\blueberry-test\wp-admin\admin.php(34): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\blueberry-test\wp-admin\plugins.php(10): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #15 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\blueberry-test\wp-includes\script-loader.php on line 2407

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please at the description and format your code to code.